# Why is Meld not identifying differences?

Tags: diff, meld

Meld is not showing differences.

In this minimal example, directories `a` and `b` are different, as shown by `diff` below.

```
$ diff a/ b/
diff a/a.txt b/a.txt
1c1
< a
---
> aa
Only in b/: b.txt
```

But Meld shows no differences.  (In Preferences, there are no text or file filters set.)

How do I get Meld to show these differences?

[image: meld]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get this result when I disable the display of new and modified files in *Meld*. The options for this can be found in the toolbar here, but this may not be the case for you. However you can also find them in the menu *→ View → File Status*; enable all three of the entries there.